# webpage image click call another webpage to load and drop down from image

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a webpage where I'm trying to figure out how to click on a image then from that image click a webpage will load in it's place but also be extended down.

Comment: Please post examples of what you've tried so far.

Comment: he means post code samples on the question, not links to third party sites

Comment: I believe that he would like an image with an onclick event that hides the image and displays new content in its place. Either that or does a thumbnail to full size image onclick and also expands the container(div maybe) and shows new html content. The url he posted had a perfect example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are maybe ways to do this I would probably just use a div which holds an img tag and hides it or use a background-img and change it to nothing.

i.e.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>
    a page
  </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var container,img;

function setup(){
  img = document.getElementById('img1');
  container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.onclick = function(){
    img.style.display = 'none';
    container.innerHTML = "HERE IS SOME OTHER CODE I 'INJECTED'\n\n <IMG src='http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lk0hdcDvTa1qjoblyo1_500.jpg'>\n HAHA ANOTHER PUG!" +
    "Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet salami spare ribs jerky tenderloin pastrami sirloin andouille ham hock. Corned beef tenderloin hamburger, pig sausage chicken andouille." +
    "Ham hock tenderloin tri-tip brisket flank strip steak hamburger bacon pork belly shank. Rump ball tip tail, filet mignon pancetta strip steak hamburger short ribs shankle" +
    "bresaola pork belly venison pork loin jowl. Ham hock kielbasa frankfurter, pancetta tenderloin shankle tail leberkas venison. Spare ribs brisket pastrami chicken bacon." +
    "Tongue tenderloin ball tip capicola. T-bone bacon venison, fatback leberkas ball tip andouille sausage pastrami tail pork chop pig. Ground round chuck t-bone," +
    " tenderloin pork belly shoulder sirloin ball tip pork chop frankfurter ham. Meatloaf ribeye jowl boudin. Shoulder tri-tip andouille filet mignon capicola." +
    " Pancetta rump pork chop venison sausage. Tenderloin t-bone boudin, swine pastrami ribeye fatback brisket sausage venison spare ribs short loin leberkas strip steak." +
    "Fatback pork chop jerky short ribs andouille bacon. Meatloaf frankfurter turducken, chuck capicola hamburger jowl sausage drumstick flank tenderloin venison shoulder" +
    " short loin ball tip. Bacon prosciutto sirloin t-bone boudin meatloaf. Pork chop swine tail shoulder short ribs pork belly shankle pork loin filet mignon short" +
    " loin sausage pastrami.";
  }
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#container{
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(126,38,36);
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="setup()">
<div id="container">
<img id="img1" src="http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lhq4onW6Vg1qbcihro1_500.jpg" />
</div>
</body>
​</html>
```

You could also adjust just the height or width of the div with the onclick event.

```
continater.style.height = 800px;
continater.style.width = 600px;
```

Thanks to: 
baconipsum.com & pugs